# How to center image inside a div, using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Here's my **HTML**:

```
<div class="overlay">
  <div id="loading">
    <img src="styles/images/30.gif">
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to make it centered vertically and horizontally.

The image is only centered horizontally, as shown on the screenshot below:

[image]

My **CSS** looks like this:

```
.overlay {
   background: #e9e9e9;
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   opacity: .5;
}

#loading {
   text-align: center;
}

#loading img {
   display: table-cell;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

What should I do to make it centered vertically? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the parent (`#loading`) height is the height of the child element (`img`). because vertical alignment doesn't make sense. set the parent of the greater height, then the inner element can be centered vertically by any available means.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.overlay {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#loading {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

#loading img {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <div id="loading">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/160x120">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you tell me what is `100vh` ?

Comment: @kurniawan26 **vh** is viewer height and it is 100% of the screen's height. And **vw** is viewer width and it is 100% of the screen's width

Comment: @Andrey it would be good if you explain what you are doing, because it seems like OP has problems understanding. Answering with just code isn't a good strategy.

Comment: @ZeusZdravkov The issue there is no problem which would require explanation. It's just a lack of knowledge. Knowledge can be obtained by reading articles, studying the code examples.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov, don't you think it would be even better if you put some words?

Comment: @ZeusZdravkov persuaded )

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve vertical alignment, many of which get complicated.

One of the simplest fixes involves setting your element to absolute positioning and margins to auto, while defining both the top and the bottom at 0.

```css
#loading {
    position: relative;
}
#loading img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

[Link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/orvn/u3j7raLb/).

Comment: Lol @ your superfluous edit [Nisse Engström](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3478852/nisse-engstr%c3%b6m). I hope you don't always impose your syntactical preferences on others.

Comment: It was suggested by someone else and went through the Suggested Edits review queue. The edit improves readability (in my opinion) and is in the same style as the code in the question, so it makes some sense at least. If you feel strongly about it, you can always unroll the changes from the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43692042/revisions).